# Rails: What in my code determines which http verb is used in a route 'call'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, http-verbs

On the [Rails Routing from the outside in](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) page, in section 2.2, there's talk of how the http verbs and URLs are used to match 4 URLs to 7 paths.

In section 2.3 it explains how helper paths are available and, sure enough, there are the 4 paths that appear to correspond with those in the table in section 2.2.

I'd like to know what determines which VERB is used when a path is called. For instance, say I have `resource :photos` and I call:

```
redirect_to photo_path(10)
```

WHAT tells me which of the 3 available verbs for that option (GET, PUT/PATCH or DELETE - according to the table in section 2.2 above) will be included as part of the route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path is path, it doesn't include `VERB` (HTTP METHOD) information. For example, path to `show` and `destroy` resource actions are by default the same and you use the same path helper (but different HTTP method):

```
<%= link_to 'show photo', photo_path(photo) %> <!-- returns 'default' link, so GET method is used here -->
<%= link_to 'delete photo', photo_path(photo), method: :delete %>
```

Redirects are performed always with `get`.

Comment: OK, but those 2 lines DO different things, right? How do they trigger different actions if the paths are the same? Is it the `method :delete` that makes the difference?

Comment: @moosefetcher yes, `method: :delete` adds attribute `data-method="delete"` to `a` tag, which indicates to the browser that it should use `DELETE` method.

Comment: Thank you. So in SOME cases you CAN control which verb is used. I'm guessing there's a whole bunch of these arbitrary facts I need to pick up - eg: 'Redirects are always performed with GET'. Rails is hugely esoteric and obfuscated at the moment. I'm guessing I'll need to ask similar questions for any number of other uni-task examples. But thank you for your reply.

Comment: @moosefetcher In most cases you can control which verb is used. There are, of course, some defaults, for example by default `form` tag uses `POST` method and regular links use `GET`, but you can change this behavior. You can't change only the method in redirect, which is always `GET`. And BTW Rails has nothing to do with this behavior - it's about HTTP protocole.

Comment: But it's Rails that seems to HIDE the information in its 'convention over configuration'. No, I don't want to have to code every last thing. I just wish the information was explained in a way that's useful for newbies. I've only just recently realised that paths effectively point to routes. Everyone was talking about checking rake routes, but I didn't even know how those routes were accessed. It's very frustrating.

Comment: No, I don't think it's *hiding* - if you don't add proper attribute, `a` tag uses `GET` and forms use `POST`. It's 'hidden' in HTML, not in Rails.

Comment: Just as a 'by the way' - I wasn't saying that Rails hides CODE; I'm saying the specific knowledge of what Rails does behind the scenes (usually by default) is hard to access when you're learning. I think online docs should prioritise explaining what the defaults are, because it's not knowing what Rails is doing FOR me that has made it very difficult to understand.

Comment: These issues are less about rails and more about the web in general, particularly, http and REST - for example, [the http standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3) defines redirects to be ([mostly](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect)) GET. Routes and the choice of http methods (GET, PUT, POST, etc.) is based on a principle of [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) called [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS).